# Merge Two Linked List

Tags: python-3.x, list, nodes

I have been trying to get this to print out but to no avail.  The error is "mergeTwoLists() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l2'"

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
       self.val = val
       self.next = next

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        if l1 is None:
            return l2
        elif l2 is None:
            return l1
        elif l1.val < l2.val:
            l1.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
            return l1
        else:
            l2.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
            return l2
            
###############################      
list1 = ListNode(1)
list1.next = ListNode(2)
list1.next.next = ListNode(4)

list2 = ListNode(1)
list2.next = ListNode(3)
list2.next.next = ListNode(4)


merged_list=Solution.mergeTwoLists(list1,list2)
while merged_list:
    print(str(merged_list.val), end = ' -> ')
    merged_list = merged_list.next
print(merged_list)
```

Comment: You need to make an instance of the `Solution` class with `()` before you can call a method on it. That's how it knows to pass `self` as the first argument: `merged_list=Solution().mergeTwoLists(list1,list2)`

Comment: Alternatively, decorate `mergeTwoLists()` with `@classmethod`, but you can't do that if this is a template from Leetcode (or similar) to evaluate your answer

Comment: add @staticmethod to before `mergeTwoLists` and call with `Solution.`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am new to this class stuff.